Creating an Unity DLL that has an external reference
I'm in the process of creating an Unity DLL for my C# scripts in Unity, however, a problem I ran into is that some of the scripts reference to an external github repository that we use. What would the best method be for me to reference that when creating the DLL? Thank you for the help!!
I tried to find a way to DLL that external reference first but I'm not sure if I could since it's not .NET structure? (I'm new to Unity and DLL so I'm not too sure if I'm doing it wrong).
